# Android - obtain url redirect

Tags: android, redirect, httpurlconnection, android-mediaplayer

I currently have a mediaplayer and am trying to get the redirect address from my source path. Since the media player does not support redirect handling, I am trying to get the redirected url path by creating a httpurlconnection etc. However, I'm not sure if I am doing it right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "create url - test");
URL testUrl = new URL(path);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)testUrl.openConnection();

String test = conn.getURL().toString();
String test1 = conn.getHeaderField(2);
String test2 = conn.toString();
Log.d(TAG, "normal stuff test is: " + test);
Log.d(TAG, "header field test is: " + test1);
Log.d(TAG, "url to string is: " + test2);
```

Comment: See if my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341475/getting-url-after-a-redirect-using-httpclient-executehttpget) helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code below follows one hop of URL redirects. By using a [HTTP HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request rather than [GET](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) it *consumes radically less bandwith*. It should be fairly straight forward to extend this method to handle multiple hops.

```
public URI followRedirects(URI original) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    HttpHead headRequest = new HttpHead(original);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(headRequest);
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY ||
        statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY)
    {
        String location = response.getHeaders("Location")[0].toString();
        String redirecturl = location.replace("Location: ", "");
        return new URI(redirecturl);
    }
    return original;
}
```

It assumes you have already set up an [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) stored in the field `client`.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612208/how-to-detect-a-redirected-url).