# GAS (google app script)/Google Drive API: Retrieving a redirected URL from pre redirect link

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-apps-script

First thank you in advance for any replies/solutions.

Disclaimer: This solution IS NOT USED FOR HOSTING IMAGES, it's for an internal process that for 100 reasons won't follow a redirect to GET the image.

This question is:
How can one use Google App Script (or Drive API) to collect the final redirected URL from a link to a google drive file (in this case a image.jpg) for pasting into a google sheet. Anyone reading this can assume that the image is shared publicly for this example.

Workflow: 
The script pulls an image file from an external URL:

```
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
```

The script then renames the image and then places it into a google drive folder using the Drive API:

```
name = String(name).toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''); //removes all spaces, sets the name lower case and then removes all extra characters
      image.setName(name);


// This would convert the file to mime type image/jpeg but it doesn't work on some gif's or jpeg 200~c

      var contentType = image.getContentType();

     try{

        if (contentType != "image/jpeg"){
          image = image.getAs('image/jpeg');
        }

      } catch (err){
        Logger.log("Didn't work");
      }

  } 
    } else {
      return imageUrl;
      }

    if (contentType === "image/jpeg"){
        var file = {
          title: name +'.jpg',
          mimeType: 'image/jpg',
          "parents": [{
          "kind": "drive#fileLink",
          "id": "folderID" //imageFolderID
           }] 
         };



        file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image);
        var driveId = file.id ;
```

Then it pastes the publicly shared link (string) for that file into a sheet for later retrieval by another program. The issue is that the link the code below produces leads to a redirect.

So the real question is: **How do I grab the final URL that this link is being redirected to? (Hint: It's not in the request or response below so I can't parse it out of those)**

An examples of the links in question:

Pre Redirect: https://googledrive.com/host/0B5gf6NnVG8VQflQwZHBMZVJiNFhlbkpEWUY3OHZnWS02ZjBZa2NBQUVCWWljVWpVWm5zcTQ/abc1.jpg

Post Redirect: https://050dfacf921e33f0950333e36cbaf7c8256bd042.googledrive.com/secure/AOjc2GPc7PRSJAfYLixwxgly6DSeHpDWD0XeuJDkW42pIe5YgjTBlwZ_MUeB-nKlYS-amWukCgcqtac4sKQs-D3ah4EFK7rPUHVwmNr0jh6EZ_1mwDfzgrToK1gUPxRUef_YKPZ4UWLYzMZYogQxuF-KwaDJsGgM5VUeQvyBDP2bfRKjCxoEMxrkewzi-Zwgp3dYgRxfWMxggLWP4Wmfadl3zJ4sD7erqU0n1yPFo8obxZt7MCx-V_PFJaG5XX0TFw6u3UehmB0oJNrSODRfbj8eh8ncNCGCkaGJ7etODSpb8fAXXULu9FAh9sc9likOEy3jezVil3xRpw0_dr3b_TXS_nBEwhFV1N7uwFONsSIRa0lThz2P4-XJnhiegtq95VCdrVDiQwFOBYgro6vEZSPefzz9PGQ-bkhwiNq7PA_7e2xCIdaMOIyoriphCdbW6FyUox405Tu60Pec9NB6pGUv78vi0Znrh5s8MJYhBInkP5CoN3obhc4qu5QrR3bro4ArtYm34A3vdg3rMhStFlatD8q4g7BOuL6iraOndgIPBHXQdwEtMqNwLhpLI59iefyRZzdNBTxm2Ly1ZInj4-EYKl4h5ajKoA==/host/0B5gf6NnVG8VQflQwZHBMZVJiNFhlbkpEWUY3OHZnWS02ZjBZa2NBQUVCWWljVWpVWm5zcTQ/abc1.jpg

My first attempt:

```
var sharedUrl = 'https://googledrive.com/host/'+ folderId + "/" + driveName;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sharedUrl);
var request = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(cleanUrl);
Logger.log(response.getContentText()); //doesn't contain the final link
Logger.log(request); //neither do I
Logger.log(response); //nope
```

Second Attempt: I have tried to work it out using traditional JS (.location) but that is not working. (Yes the code below makes 0 sense at this point but my multiple iterations aren't working either:

```
//        Logger.log("Page location is " + cleanUrl.location.href);
```

3rd Attempt: I found this Stack Link
[How to detect a redirected URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612208/how-to-detect-a-redirected-url)

But I am unable to work this correctly:

```
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY || statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY){
        String location = response.getHeaders("Location")[0].toString();
        String redirecturl = location.replace("Location: ", "");
    }
}
```

Any encouragement, help or just general banter would be appreciated, and thanks to anyone who is willing to throw in their two cents!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default Google Apps Script followredirects is true so you won't find Location header. so you need to set it as false as below.

```
var url ='https://googledrive.com/host/' + file.id;
var options = {"method" : "GET","followRedirects" : false};
var redirecturl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getAllHeaders().Location;
```